# Checking if something is a unit

Tags: field-theory, ideals

Check if $\mathbb{Z}_5/x^2 + 3x + 1$ is a field. Is $(x+2)$ a unit, if so calculate its inverse.

I would say that this quotient ring is not a field, because $<x^2 + 3x + 1>$ is not a maximal ideal, since $x^2 + 3x + 1 = (x+4)^2$ is not irreducible.

However, the result should still be a ring, right? How do I check if $(x+2)$ is a unit in that ring. Should I just "try" to invert it, or is there a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that if it has an inverse, it's a degree 1 polynomial. It is easy to check
$$
(x+2)(x+a)=x^2+(2+a)x+2a.
$$
This needs to satisfy $2+a\equiv 3\mod 5$ and $2a\equiv 2\mod 5$, so that subtracting out one copy of $x^2+3x+1$ yields zero. You can check all cases now.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$(x+4)^2-2^2=(x+4+2)(x+4-2)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ y:=x\!+\!2,\,\ 0 = (x\!+\!4)^2\!= (y\!+\!2)^2 = y^2\!-y-1\,\Rightarrow\, y(\color{#c00}{y\!-\!1}) = 1\,\Rightarrow\,y^{-1}\!=\color{#c00}{y\!-\!1} = x\!+\!1$

**Remark** $\ $ This works generally: if $\,f(b/a)\ne 0\,$ then we can  invert $\,y = ax\!-\!b\pmod{\!f(x)}\,$ by *changing variables*: $ $ substitute $\,x = (y\!-\!b)/a\,$ in $\,f(x)\equiv 0\,$  to obtain $\,g(y)y-c \equiv 0,\,$ hence $\,y^{-1} \equiv g(y)/c,\,$ where $\,c\not\equiv 0\,$ (else $\,f(b/a)=0\,$ contra hypothesis). Here I assume that the coefficient ring is a field (or that $\,c\,$ is a unit), so $\,c^{-1}$ exists. More generally, one can employ *resultants* or other elimination techniques such as Grobner bases.